# Integration in Evans’ PDE in Chapter 2

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

These are the information about this question.
[image: this is the first function]

[image: This is what phi is]

In this case, f is a twice differentiable function and compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
My question is I do not know how does the $C\epsilon^2$ come out for $n\geq3$.
My processes for it is the following,

$$\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\Phi(y)dy=C\int_{B(0,\epsilon)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}=C\int_{0}^{\epsilon} \left(\int_{\partial B(0,r)} \frac{1}{r^{n-2}} dS \right)dr $$

But then I got confused about what to do next. Is there any hint for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral
$$\int_{\partial B^n(0,r)}\frac{1}{r^{n-2}}\mathrm d\mu^{n-1}$$
Is just the integration of a constant, and thus is equal to the measure of the set being integrated on, multiplied by the constant itself, i.e
$$\int_{\partial B^n(0,r)}\frac{1}{r^{n-2}}\mathrm d\mu^{n-1}=A_n(r)~ \frac{1}{r^{n-2}}$$
Where $A_n(r)$ is the surface area of the sphere $\partial B^n(0,r)$. But, we know that
$$A_n(r)=r^{n-1}A_n(1)$$
and hence
$$\int_{\partial B^n(0,r)}\frac{1}{r^{n-2}}\mathrm d\mu^{n-1}=A_n(1)\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{n-2}}=A_n(1)~r$$

Plugging this into the integral with $\epsilon$,
$$\text{const.}\cdot\int_{B^n(0,\epsilon)}\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}\mathrm d^{n}x=\text{const.}\cdot \int_0^\epsilon\left(\int_{\partial B^n(0,r)}\frac{1}{r^{n-2}}\mathrm d\mu^{n-1}\right)\mathrm dr \\ =\text{const.}\cdot\int_0^\epsilon A_n(1) ~r~\mathrm dr \\ =\text{const.}\cdot \epsilon^2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I totally did not see that r is fixed in the inner integral.